# Android GridView: Growing from center until numColumns is reached

Tags: android, xml, listview, gridview

I have a gridview that with android:numColumns="8". When there are less than 8 items in the GridView adapter, my goal is to have those columns centered inside the gridview.

Right now this is what I'm working with:

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <GridView android:id="@+id/roomDashboardUsers"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="70dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="8"
            android:stretchMode="none"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```